# Impact of Discrete and linear dividends on Local Volatility model

Tags: option-pricing, local-volatility, dividends

I am trying to understand the assumptions and weaknesses of a Dupire Local Volatility model.

If dividends are assumed **linear**, is it a problem for model calibration? If yes, why?

Why would large values of discrete dividends cause calibration problems?

Is there a pedagogical resource to understand these limitations of Local Volatility models?

Comment: I would suggest to read the excellent paper by Hans Buehler: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1141877